# How Load specific key of an json file and create a string using the list of values under that key?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am parsing a main json which has the full data in scala. Then I need to load another json which has required attribute for filtering for each object such as Orders is one of them. I need to read all the values without hardcoding any keys. Then i need to create a string in this way for the Order Object "order_id,customers.customerId". Can you help me in creating this string

```
{
    "Orders": {
        "orderid": "order_id",
        "customerId": "customers.customerId"
    },
    "Products": {
        "productid": "product_id",
        "productName": "products.productName"
    }
}
```

Can you help me with it in scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> data
res13: String =
{
    "Orders": {
        "orderid": "order_id",
        "customerId": "customers.customerId"
    },
    "Products": {
        "productid": "product_id",
        "productName": "products.productName"
    }
}
```

```
scala> val df = Seq(data).toDF("input")
```

```
scala> val colExprs = """
    CONCAT_WS(
        ',',
        MAP_VALUES(
            FROM_JSON(
                input,
                'Orders map<string, string>'
            ).orders
        )
    ) AS output    
"""
```

```
scala> df.selectExpr(colExprs).show(false)
+-----------------------------+
|output                       |
+-----------------------------+
|order_id,customers.customerId|
+-----------------------------+
```

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

df
.withColumn("jMap", expr("from_json(input, 'map<string, map<string,string>>')"))
.withColumn("keys", map_keys($"jMap"))
.selectExpr("inline(transform(keys, k -> named_struct('key', k,'value',concat_ws(',', map_values(jMap[k]))) ))")
.show(false)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+--------+-------------------------------+
|key     |value                          |
+--------+-------------------------------+
|Orders  |order_id,customers.customerId  |
|Products|product_id,products.productName|
+--------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for awesome answer. sorry to ask one more question. What if my df is having columns for Order and product and they are having the key value list. e.g dArray[String] = Array(Orders, Products)

Comment: updated, answer .. is that you wanted ?

Comment: This is my df after i read the json data. 
|Orders                          |Products                          |
+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|{customers.customerId, order_id}|{products.productName, product_id}
on top of this df i want to do the same operation

Comment: Its not clear above ask.. please create new question with detailed input & expected output.

Comment: got it. let me do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78179567/how-to-generate-the-concatted-list-of-values-from-json-in-scala

Comment: done, answered in that.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the maven package `play-json` (`version: 2.7.4, scala: 2.13`) to achieve the following results. On a high-level, parse the JSON string -> convert the string to a map for each kv pair -> generate the string of interest using `mkString`

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

val jsonString = """
{
    "Orders": {
        "orderid": "order_id",
        "customerId": "customers.customerId"
    },
    "Products": {
        "productid": "product_id",
        "productName": "products.productName"
    }
}
"""



def returnKeysOfInterest(jsonString: String, keyName: String): String = {
  val json: JsValue = Json.parse(jsonString)
  val map: Map[String, JsValue] = json.as[Map[String, JsValue]]
  val keysMap: Map[String, String] = map(keyName).as[Map[String, String]]

  val keysString: String = map(keyName).as[Map[String, String]].values.mkString(",")

  keysString
}

returnKeysOfInterest(jsonString, "Orders") // order_id,customers.customerId
```

Here, I have assumed the kv pair to have one-level of nesting as suggested by the input shared by you. If there are more levels of nesting then we can modify the `keysString` variable accordingly.

Another variant of the `keysString` variable with `foldLeft` can be :

```scala
val keysString: String = keysMap.values.foldLeft("")((a, b) => if (a.isEmpty) b else a + "," + b)
```