# how to generate the concatted list of values from JSON in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Input Data in a json file:

```
[{
    "Orders": {
        "orderid": "order_id",
        "customerId": "customers.customerId"
    },
    "Products": {
        "productid": "product_id",
        "productName": "products.productName"
    }
}]
```

When i read it using spark.read.json("filepath"), this is the output i get.

```
|Orders                          |Products                          |
+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|{customers.customerId, order_id}|{products.productName, product_id}
```

I want to pass Order as a variable and generate the list of values concated e.g order_id,customers.customerId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> fdf.show(false)
+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|Orders                          |Products                          |
+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|{customers.customerId, order_id}|{products.productName, product_id}|
+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

```
scala> val inCols = Seq("orders") // You can add products as well in this list
```

```
scala> val colExprs = inCols.map{ c => s"concat_ws('', array(${c}.*)) as ${c}"}
```

```
scala> fdf.selectExpr(colExprs:_*).show(false)
```

```
+----------------------------+
|orders                      |
+----------------------------+
|customers.customerIdorder_id|
+----------------------------+
```